# Rails gmail gem: Get correct address of sender and message body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, gmail-imap

I'm using [nu7'hatch/gmail](https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail) gem to get into my Gmail account and get the e-mails. I can grab the `Date` and `Subject` correctly, but for the `From` and `Body` I also get these characters and I'm not able to simply get the text:

From:

`--- - !ruby/struct:Net::IMAP::Address name: [NAME_OF_SENDER_IS_HERE] route: mailbox: [USERNAME_OF_SENDER_IS_HERE] host: gmail.com`

Body:
`--- !ruby/object:Mail::Body boundary: preamble: epilogue: charset: US-ASCII part_sort_order: - text/plain - text/enriched - text/html parts: !ruby/array:Mail::PartsList [] raw_source: [MESSAGE_GOES_HERE] encoding: 7bit`

Is there any way to correctly get the From and Body text, without these characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work-around that I found is with Net::IMAP.

Note that the email needed from `From` is done `mail.from[0]`.

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
imap.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
imap.select('Inbox')

imap.search(["ALL"]).each do |message_id|
  emails = imap.fetch(message_id,'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822']
  mail = Mail.read_from_string emails
  @email = Email.create(:subject => mail.subject, :message => mail.body.decoded, :sender => mail.from[0], :date => mail.date)
end

imap.disconnect
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

This line returns the complete struct:

```
gmail.inbox.find(subject: "yoursubject").first.envelope
```

...on the struct you can:

```
gmail.inbox.find(subject: "yoursubject").first.envelope.reply_to[0].mailbox
gmail.inbox.find(subject: "yoursubject").first.envelope.reply_to[0].name
gmail.inbox.find(subject: "yoursubject").first.envelope.reply_to[0].host
```

...and then do your manipulations to combine into a single string which would be evaluated to:

```
name <sample@sample.com>
```